# Joining entities together

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller

I have the following two entities that make up my database -

```
public class App
{
    public int AppID { get; set; }
    public string Business { get; set; }
    public string ApName { get; set; }
    public string FirstContact { get; set; }

    public virtual Colleague Colleague { get; set; }
}


public class Colleague
{
    public int ColleagueID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public int PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<App> App { get; set; }
}
```

The colleague entity can have multiple different applications, hence the collection, but i can't figure out how to actually link the tables together with this.

At the moment I am seeding my entities like below, but how do i modify this seeding data to show which app a colleague should be associated with?

```
        var colleagues  = new List<Colleague>
        {
            new Colleague{FirstName="test", SecondName="test", EmailAddress="test@test.hotmail.com", PhoneNumber=000000},
            new Colleague{FirstName="test2", SecondName="test2", EmailAddress="test@test.hotmail.com", PhoneNumber=000000},
            new Colleague{FirstName="test3", SecondName="test3", EmailAddress="test@test.hotmail.com", PhoneNumber=000000},
        };

        colleagues.ForEach(s => context.Colleagues.Add(s));

        var apps = new List<App>
        {
        new App{ApName="app1",Business="business"},
        new App{ApName="app2",Business="business"},
        new App{ApName="app3",Business="business"},
        new App{ApName="app4",Business="business"},
        new App{ApName="app5",Business="business"},
        new App{ApName="app6",Business="business"},
        new App{ApName="app7",Business="business"},
        };
        apps.ForEach(s => context.Apps.Add(s));
        context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

With that model you are creating a **one-to-many relationship**,so EF will create for you a `ColleageId` FK in your `Apps` Table.

[image: FK]

Now, you have multiple options to update your data. Let gets start with `Colleague`. My first recomendation is add a constructor to initialize your collection:

```
public Colleague()
{
   Apps=new HashSet<App>();// Could be a List<> too
}
```

Now, suppose that you want to add a new `Colleague` with a new `App` too, and you want to relate both. Your code would be like this:

```
 var newColleague=new Colleague{FirstName="test4", SecondName="test4", EmailAddress="test4@test.hotmail.com", PhoneNumber=000000};
 newColleage.Add( new App{ApName="app7",Business="business"});
 context.Add(newColleague);
 context.SaveChanges();
```

And EF will save both entities, you don't need to add  the new `App` in its `DBSet`.

The second escenario is if you want to add a new `App` in a `Colleague` that is in DB:

```
var colleage=context.FirstOrDefault(c=>c.EmailAddress=="test@test.hotmail.com");
colleage.Apps.Add(new App{ApName="app8",Business="business"});
context.SaveChanges();
```

The third escenario is if both are in the DB. In that case you have to find then to relate them later:

```
var colleage=context.FirstOrDefault(c=>c.EmailAddress=="test@test.hotmail.com");
var app=context.FirstOrDefault(a=>a.ApName=="app1");
colleague.Add(app);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Now in the case of `App`, to modify its relationship with `Colleague`, you can do this:

```
var colleage=context.FirstOrDefault(c=>c.EmailAddress=="test@test.hotmail.com");
var app=context.FirstOrDefault(a=>a.ApName=="app1");
app.Colleague=colleague;
context.SaveChanges();
```

BTW, you can use the `AddRange` method when you want to add more than one element to your `DBSet`:

```
context.Colleagues.AddRange(colleagues);
```